# Java eclipse Error: Could not find main class after export

Tags: java, executable-jar

How to get a executable jar file?
When I try to launch my newly exported jar file nothing happens and when i run it from the terminal i get: `Error: Could not find or load main class smallGame.SmallGame` Hope my printscreen below answers most questions to solve this problem.[image: print screen]

Comment: At least take time in printing your screen... Please, post a code instead.

Comment: @Maroun I don't think my problem is in my code since it runs in eclipse?

Comment: It will help us helping you if you post relevant snippets instead, imagine someone wants to try to reproduce by copying-pasting your code.

Comment: Did you export as JAR file or as a Runnable Jar File?  These will create difference manifest files

Comment: @purringpigeon runnable jar

Comment: What does your manifest look like?  Can you post that here?